# Using Rust to convert PCL stream to tiff image

Tags: rust, pcl

Rust newbie here.  I hope someone can advise me and provide a "fix".  I am making a virtual print "server" that listens for PCL print streams from a legacy system and then should convert the PCL into tiff images.  The PCL streams should basically result in a tiff with an image version of the PCL stream.  Here's a snippet of my code for the handler that converts the PCL to TIFF:

```
fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream, config: &VirtualPrinterConfig) {
    let keyword_regex = Regex::new(&config.keyword_pattern).unwrap();
    let mut file_name = format!("{}_{:}", config.name, Local::now().format("%y%m%d_%H%M%S"));

    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    loop {
        let mut chunk = [0u8; 4096];
        let len = match stream.read(&mut chunk) {
            Ok(0) => break, // End of stream
            Ok(len) => len,
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Error reading from stream: {}", e);
                break;
            }
        };
        buf.extend_from_slice(&chunk[..len]);
    }

    if keyword_regex.is_match(std::str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap()) {
        file_name.push_str(&format!("_{}", &config.keyword_pattern));
    }

    let mut file_path = std::path::PathBuf::from(&config.output_folder);
    file_path.push(format!("{}.tif", file_name));

    let mut tiff = tiff::encoder::TiffEncoder::new(std::fs::File::create(&file_path).unwrap()).unwrap();
    tiff.write_image::<tiff::encoder::colortype::Gray8>(256, 256, &buf).unwrap();
    println!("Saved file: {:?}", file_path);
}
```

At this time, the virtual printer is running and it accepts a PCL stream from the legacy system which is cool.  However before I could get too excited I saw that the resulting tiff looks scrambled like a broken "TV" :).  (should look like an image of a text based report).  I need the file to be in tiff format before the resulting tiff image of the report is used to archive into a document repository..  Example of the scrambled tiff I get is below.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the code to save the PCL into a legible tiff file?  I appreciate any tips and code to get this working.  I don't know if this matters but the Rust program with the virtual server will be run on a Windows server/computer.

PS - you'll notice there's a keyword_regex part of the code.  I don't think that is a cause of the issue but basically it is supposed to name the tiff in a certain way if some defined keywords are seen in the incoming PCL stream.

Cheers!

Comment: You haven't said what crate your TIFF encoder comes from. Is it even expecting PCL? My guess would be that it's expecting a bitmap. Your code appears to be pointing to some data in memory and you're telling it that that memory is a 256x256 image in grayscale 1-byte-per pixel format. I would expect PCL to represent a much larger full printed page (and PCL is not a bitmap format). If my off-the-cuff guesses are correct, you'd first need to render the PCL, then pass that data to your TIFF encoder. But, there isn't enough information in the post to tell us for sure.

Comment: Unless there is something weird going on it's [`tiff::encoder::TiffEncoder`](https://docs.rs/tiff/latest/tiff/encoder/struct.TiffEncoder.html) as OP uses the full path in their code.

Comment: Stuff such as `keyword_regex` should be removed before posting on SO because a [mre] is way easier to debug, help with and later on connect to a future visitors own code.